# Symfony 5 Doctrine Fixtures --purge-with-truncate fail with Syntax error or access violation: 1701

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have tables with foreign keys.
When I execute this command:

> php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate

it will failed with this message:

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]:
> Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table
> referenced in a foreign key constraint (`shipments`.`document`,
> CONSTRAINT `FK_D8698A76D19302F8` FOREIGN KEY (`assignment_id`)
> REFERENCES `shipments`.`assignment` (`id`))

Is there a possibility to truncate the tables without checking foreign key constraints?
It is annoying to truncate all the tables manually before executing the fixtures...

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to avoid this behavior. It is known issue in fixtures.

Choose the solution which is better for you:

### 1. CLI usage:

[Source](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/50#issuecomment-395918939)

```
    bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force \
    && bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force \
    && bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load -n
```

### 2. Your own command (1):

Depends on your database engine you can disable the foregin key checks for that moment before you run doctrine:fixtures:load command and after that turn it on. You can achieve it by creating your own command.

Some pseudo code for MySQL:

```
    public function loadFixtures(): void
    {
        $this->disableForeignKeyChecks();
        $this->runFixturesLoadCommand();
        $this->enableForeignKeyChecks();
    }

    public function enableForeignKeyChecks(): void
    {
        $currentValue = $this->connection->fetchOne('SELECT @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks');
        if ('1' === $currentValue) {
            return;
        }

        $this->connection->executeStatement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
    }

    public function disableForeignKeyChecks(): void
    {
        $currentValue = $this->connection->fetchOne('SELECT @@SESSION.foreign_key_checks');
        if ('0' === $currentValue) {
            return;
        }

        $this->connection->executeStatement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    }
```

### 3. Your own command / Makefile (2):

You could create your own one command which call all 3 commands from 1st point or if you know and use Makefile just create Makefile command with these 3 commands.
It is also already mentioned in the github here (Symfony Command solution): [link](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/50#issuecomment-316967215)